# Not able to juice a guava

Tags: juice, juicing, guava

Well I have a Jack LaLaine Power Juicer Express. This did not work so well with the ripe guavas. Twelve washed and whole guavas and no juice. Lots of pulp though. Decided to scrape all this pulp out into a Ninja processor and pureed with about 1 cup of filtered water. Pulp is still quite dense even with the added water. Then strained it through a wired sieve. Going to freeze these in some neoprene ice cube trays with push out bottoms and seal them up in 1 gallon FoodSaver zip lock bags for individual uses, mix & match. Cubes equal roughly 1 tablespoon each.

I keep hearing you should use any juice asap but that isn't always possible so I decided freezing was the next best option.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Welcome! Can you please clarify what your question is? We're a Q&A site and it's important that questions be clear... are you asking why you couldn't juice the guava? Are you asking how soon to use the juice? What is it you want us to answer?

Comment: You might try a cold press juicer instead, they tend to have a higher juice yield than the centrifugal type. I juice guavas with no issues in mine. With all the filtering and freezing and grinding you're doing to make that juice now there probably isn't much guava left in it anyways.

Comment: It is a bit complicated. I suggest you look at this website for preparation instructions: http://www.vegrecipesofindia.com/guava-juice-recipe/

Comment: Guava strands are pretty strong, so I can see how the Jack LaLane blades wouldn't cut them well. Surprised the (20krpm?) Ninja didn't do better. Perhaps still too thick with one cup water. You've got to let the thing get up to speed, without cavitating, to get the best blending. I tilt my Ninja around while running to ensure the best flow past blades.

Comment: Related: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/20878/48351